# Why Mobile Landscape mode + using keyboard in form mess everything up?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I make it simple:
This is before I do type anything:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/7683bca9473905850c375885269354745c7a847e.png everything is normal.

When you type on one of the forms the website totally gets messed up, probably because the device thinks the viewport is smaller (At least at my site):
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/51402c0f3db0c0b4ab0fef0a305982608545606e.png

There is a way I can fix this?
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>RFP - How to ripen Avocado</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="keywords" content="How to ripen avocado, avocado, ripen, RFP bags, climacteric fruits">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="stopFlowMobile"> <!--This tag will stop overflow in mobiles-->
        <div id="divStyle1">
            <header>
                <h1>
                    <span><span class="importantH1" id="importantH1">RIPEN AVOCADO's</span> <span id="widthH1">with</span> <span class="importantH1">RFP Bags!</span></span>
                    <span id="line2H1">Ripens fruits and vegetables in as little as 12 hours!</span>
                </h1>
            </header>

            <main>
                    <div id="purpuleLineBox">
                        <div id="purpuleLine1" class="purpuleHover"> <p>100% recyclable and bio-degradable</p> </div>
                        <div id="purpuleLine2" class="purpuleHover"> <p>Organically speeds up the natural ripening process</p> </div>
                        <div id="purpuleLine3" class="purpuleHover"> <p>The quickest way to achieve the perfect avocado taste</p> </div>
                        <div id="purpuleLine5" class="purpuleHover"> <p>The bag tells you exactly when the avocado is fully ripen</p> </div>
                        <div id="purpuleLine4" class="purpuleHover"> <p>Works with Mango, Banana, Peach, and another climacteric fruits</p> </div>
                    </div>

                    <img id="logoImg" src="Logo.png" alt="RFP bag that ripen avocado">
                </main>
        </div>

        <div class="divStyleBottom">
                <a class="buttonMobile" href="#to1"><button class="moreButton">More</button></a>
        </div>

        <div id="divStyle2">
            <h3 id="to1">Do you want to try our new product ?</h3>
            <form id="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/2/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBJHw1Q6YlwO_0s2OgMhuyQEj4PLvToM1N1G5BEYQRiZlCLQ/formResponse">
                <label for="">It's FREE</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="inputs" id="input1" name="entry.1045366435">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" id="input2" name="entry.1398681060">
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" id="input3" name="entry.403219718"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
            <aside> <!--Only for design - apple and tomato images-->
                <img src="Apple.png" id="apple" alt="Apple Image">
                <img src="Tomato.png" id="tomato" alt="Tomato, Can be ripen by RFP bag">
            </aside>
        </div>

        <div class="divStyleBottom">
                <a href="#to2" class="buttonMobile"><button class="moreButton">More</button></a>
        </div>

        <div id="divStyle3">
            <section>
                <h4>What people already tried ?</h4>
                <div id="boxIframes">
                    <iframe src="https://www.today.com/food/how-ripen-avocado-quickly-days-or-even-minutes-t126914" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://www.thekitchn.com/can-you-really-ripen-an-avocado-in-just-10-minutes-223006" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    <iframe src="https://www.littlethings.com/how-to-ripen-avocados-fast/1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <!--Credit-->
        <div class="divStyleBottom" id="to2">
            <footer>
                <p>Created By: liranweb99@gmail.com</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--For mobiles in regular mode - "turn the device" -->
    <img src="RotateMobile.gif" alt="" id="rotateAnimation">
    <p id="rotateText">Please turn your device</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style - all devices:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*Backgrounds*/

#divStyle1 {
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #016087;
}

.divStyleBottom {
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #1D232F;
}

#divStyle2 {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #016087;
}

#divStyle3 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #016087;
}



* {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*H1*/

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    top: 2vh;
}

h1>span {
    display: block;
}

.importantH1 {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 4vw;
}

#importantH1 {
    margin-right: 0.7%;
}

#widthH1 {
    font-size: 3.6vw;
}

#line2H1 {
    font-size: 2.1vw;
}

/*Purple Lines*/

#purpuleLineBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23%;
}

#purpuleLine1 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 32vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


#purpuleLine2 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 43vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine3 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 46vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine4 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 54vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine5 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 48.2vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div>p {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin-left: 7px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
}

.purpuleHover {
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-origin: top left;
    cursor: default;
}

.purpuleHover:hover {
    transform: scale(1.17);
    z-index: 1;
}


/*Logo*/

#logoImg {
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 10vh;
    transform: rotate(8deg);
    border: 20px dashed white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 30vw;
    height:73vh;
}

/*More buttons*/

.moreButton {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 80%;
    width: 8.5%;
    border: 13px double rgb(37, 92, 163);
    background-color: rgb(113, 189, 214);
    cursor: pointer;
}

a>button {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 6.5px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#to2 {
    height: 8.2vh;
}

/*H3 - Do you want to try our product*/

h3 {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    cursor: default;
}

/*Form*/

form {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 19%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;    
    border-top: 5px solid white;    
    border-radius: 8%;
    padding: 10px;
}

label {
    font-size: 2.35vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
}

.inputs {
    width: 47%;
    height: 8%;
    border-radius: 1%;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

#input1 {    
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 20%;
}

#input2 {    
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 20%;
}

textarea {
    width: 70%;
    height: 45%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    resize: none;
}

#submit {
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px double white;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 32%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#submit:active {
    width: 11%;
    height: 11%;
}

/*Fruist images, Page 2*/

#apple {
    position: absolute;
    left: -4%;
    top: 103%;
    width: 22vw;
    height: 28vh;
}

#tomato {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10%;
    top: 176%;
    zoom: 70%;
}

/*H4 - What people alreay treid*/

h4 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    right: 1.7%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 4vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 10vh;
    cursor: default;
}

/*3 Iframes of different websites*/

iframe {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right:2% ;
    height: 65vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 17vh;
    right: 1.3%;
    border: 8px solid black;
}

section {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/*Credit*/

footer>p {
    font-size: 250%;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 1.3vh;
}

/*Disable phone animations*/

@media screen and (min-width:1025px)
{
    #rotateAnimation {
        display: none;
    }

    #rotateText {
        display: none;
    }
}

#stopFlowMobile {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait) /*Animation of regular mode for mobiles*/
    {

        body {
            background-color: #016087;
        }

        #stopFlowMobile {
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        #rotateAnimation {
            width: 80vw;
            height: 60vh;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 30vh;
        }

        #rotateText {
            font-size: 300%;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
            border-top: 3vh solid #D52C82;
            border-bottom: 3vh solid #D52C82;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation:landscape)  /*State for land mode mobiles*/
    {
        #rotateAnimation, #rotateText {
            display: none;
        }

        #stopFlowMobile {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        #purpuleLineBox {
            position: unset;
            margin-top: 10vh;
        }


        #purpuleLine1 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }


        #purpuleLine2 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #purpuleLine3 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #purpuleLine4 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #purpuleLine5 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .buttonMobile {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0.8vh;
        }

        .moreButton {
            border: 7px double rgb(37, 92, 163);
        }

        #apple {
            top: 100vh;
        }

        #tomato {
            top: 250vh;
            width: 50vw;
            height: 55vh;
        }

        #submit {
            width: 10vw;
            height: 9vh;
        }

        #boxIframes {
            position: absolute;
            left: 8%;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 25%;
            border: 5px solid black;
        }

        footer>p {
            font-size: 140%;
            top: 0.5vh;
        }
    }
}
```

http://howtoripen.com/